# How to pass arguments based on term filter

Tags: 7, views

I have content type called 'software' and added taxonomy terms to this content type as select list. There are 10 taxonomy terms in that list. 
And now I have created 10 pages under this 'software' content type with 10 different taxonomy terms selected among them.

```
> Page1 -> Term1 
> Page2 -> Term2 
> etc.
```

What I need is, If i see www.mysite.com/taxonomy/term/3  in the url, I need to display only the page title of the listed nodes in the view (rather than the title and teaser), for those nodes tagged with taxonomy term(3).

How can I achieve using views arguments and filters?

Comment: which version of drupal?

Comment: sisko@ Drupal7 am using..any solution...

Comment: In My View, I have selected as : Fields: content titel and in Filter: type=software. and how to add filters and arguments for this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, here are the steps you'd need to take to override the default taxonomy term view with your own customized one.

- Go to the listing of available views on your site at **/admin/structure/views** and at the bottom of the page you'll see grayed out views that are not enabled.  One of them will be the Taxonomy term view which is delivered by default with the module.  Let's go ahead and clone it, so we can customize to fit our needs.
- Hit '**clone**' next to that view, in the drop-down options and rename it to something like 'Custom Taxonomy term'

[image]

- Next, navigate to the 'Page' display and change the Format to display '**Fields**' instead of 'Content: Teaser'

[image]

- Add whatever fields you want.  It sounds like in your case, you'd want to add the Title field.  I would uncheck the label from being displayed (uncheck '**Create label**') when configuring the field.

[image]

- Finally, save and navigate to your view again: www.mysite.com/taxonomy/term/3 and see the change!  Your new view should be picked up and will replace the old one.

Go ahead and beautify and edit as you please from now on to customize the default terms view.  Hope this helps!